# Logstash GROK for single letter

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

i have the below log please help me to parse it as I am not able to go beyond, date and time

```
[Fri Aug 05 11:32:10 2016] [D] [17819(139987138922464)] checking [/libs/granite/csrf/token.json]
```

Comment: Please show the current grok pattern you have now

Comment: And also what values you wish to extract.